# Как сделать запись экрана в С++ Builder Embarcadero?

Tags: c++, c++builder, embarcadero

Подскажите - Как сделать видеозапись экрана в С++ Builder Embarcadero при нажатии на кнопку?
Пробовал использовать OpenCV и FFMPEG - убил пару дней, не срослось. Подскажите как сделать самым коротким способом, заранее благодарю за ответы!

Comment: На чистом WinAPI, без библиотек:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291167/how-can-i-take-a-screenshot-in-a-windows-application

Comment: Видео запись экрана, не скриншёт